Diferencial Equations solve $\frac{e^{2x}+2x}{e^{x}}dy-(1+2y)dx=0$
Guys i'm having trouble with one exercícies:
Solve $\frac{e^{2x}+2x}{e^{x}}dy-(1+2y)dx=0$
what i'm doing:
I'm trying to group by differences
$\frac{e^{2x}+2x}{e^{x}}dy=(1+2y)dx$
$\frac{dy}{1+2y}=\frac{e^{x}}{e^{2x}+2x}dx$
is that correct? i don't know how integrate that expression $\frac{e^{x}}{e^{2x}+2x}dx$

I'm getting an integrand along the lines of $\frac{1}{u^2+2\ln u}$. But feeding this in Wolfram doesn't give any result

@Cesario after that? Can we also take $2x=2 \ln u$?

WA finds a very complicated solution.

@KurtG.. Do you really think that this is a result ? Cheers :-)

@ClaudeLeibovici Probably not. It rewrites the "solution" formally as the general solution of the homogeneous equation plus a special case of the inhomogeneous equation. This WA link is more to clarify a deleted comment by someone who claimed that the solutions are constants.

N.b. there is a unique constant solution, $y(x) = -\frac12$.

I am afraid that only a series solution would give a result.
For example (using @Travis Willse's suggestion in comments), this would give
$$y=C +(2C+1)\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n+1}\, a_n\, x^n$$ the first coefficients being
$$\left\{1,\frac{1}{2},\frac{7}{6},\frac{65}{24},\frac{811}{120},
   \frac{4343}{240},\frac{28319}{560},\frac{1175941}{8064},\frac{15
   6309763}{362880},\frac{4705295981}{3628800}\right\}$$ which do not correspond to any sequence in $OEIS$.
If we consider the integral form you properly wrote
$$\int\frac{dy}{1+2y}=\int\frac{e^{x}}{e^{2x}+2x}\,dx$$ assuming that you are optimistic, you could write
$$\frac{e^{x}}{e^{2x}+2x}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n\,2^n\,x^n\,e^{-(2n+1)x}$$ and use
$$\int x^n\,e^{-(2n+1)x}\,dx=-(2 n+1)^{-(n+1)}\, \Gamma (n+1,(2 n+1)x)$$ which would give
$$\frac{1}{2} \log (2 y+1)=C+\frac 12\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^{n+1}\,\left(\frac{2}{2 n+1}\right)^{n+1}\, \Gamma (n+1,(2 n+1)x)$$

N.b. we can write your series solution as $y(x) = c + (1 + 2 c) \left(x - \frac12 ^2 + \frac76 x^3 + \cdots\right)$.

Much better ! Put int in an answer. If you don't want to do itI shall qoting you. Cheers. :-),

Please put it in yours, then---I don't think I have anything else to add about the problem, except that there's a constant solution $c = -\frac12$. (The quadratic term in my previous comment is missing an $x$.)

This function can't be integrated .Only a part of this equation can be integrated and not the full .Note that many functions like this can't be integrated or anti derivative can't be found .This can be expanded by only using Maclaurin series or Taylor series. And even this too would only give an approximate answer and not accurate.
$e^x=1+\frac{x}{1!}+\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^3}{3!}...$
